# Remove password protected posts from default RSS feed

Tags: posts, rss, password

I want to remove all password protected posts from the default RSS feed. Unfortunately I was only able to find one code example, but it looks like something is missing.

```
function rss_filter_protected( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_feed ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'rss_filter_password_where' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','rss_filter_protected' );
```

As soon as I save this function the RSS feed displays all post types (attachments, etc.) that are registered to the system instead of only published posts.

If possible I would like to solve this without an additional plugin.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe you need to use `posts_where`, you're given the query object in the filter so just tell it you don't want passworded posts using `$query->set(...`

Comment: Thank you, Tom! `$query->set( 'has_password', false );` did the job. I didn't knew that was possible.

Comment: can you post that as a solution below? I can't upvote and give you points for comments :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the filter to exclude password protected posts from the default RSS feed:

```
function rss_filter_protected( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_feed ) {
        $query->set( 'has_password', false );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts','rss_filter_protected' );
```